# C# to VB.NET syntax conversion for class instantiation with properties

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-4.0, anonymous-types

I am working with Workflow Foundations 4 (in C#) and am trying to write a VB.NET expression. Is there a way to do the following in VB.NET on one line?

```
SomeObj instance = new SomeObj()
{ 
    SomeStringProp = "a",
    SomeIntProp = 17
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately Window Workflow 4 doesn't (or didn't at the time) give you the option to use C# in your Expressions in the activities.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
Dim instance = new SomeObj() With {
    .ISomeStringProp = "a", 
    .SomeIntProp = 17
}
```

If you want more info take a look at *[VB.NET 9.0: Object and Array Initializers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2008/02/05/vb-net-9-0-object-and-array-initializers.aspx)*.

Comment: +1 on the example, think the quip about google is unnecessary, though. Stackoverflow is supposed to house the answers to the difficult as well as the trivial, whether or not the answer already exists elsewhere on the interwebs.

Comment: Out of curiosity what was the exact phrasing you used when googling?

Comment: @terrance "object initializer vb.net" :)