# visual basic equivalent of "rectangle a=new a() { width=1; height=2; }"

Tags: c#, vb.net, initialization, object-initializers

```
rectangle a=new a() { width=1; height=2; }
```

I used to construct objects like this, it there a similar way to do this in visual basic?
I'm sorry I couldn't really label the technique.

Comment: This is a C# [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936224/c-sharp-to-vb-net-syntax-conversion-for-class-instantiation-with-properties

Comment: In an object initializer, use commas not semicolons. You can leave out the `()` in C# when you use the parameterless instance constructor together with an object initializer. The type (class) is hardly called `a` when the variable is `a`. Use `rectangle` or whatever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Object initializer in VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385125.aspx):

```
Dim a = New Rectangle With { .width = 1, .height = 2 }
```

Answer (score -1):

The `Rectangle` has a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9wcdy991.aspx) to define width and height:

```
Dim r As New Rectangle(1, 1, 200, 300) 'x,y,width,height
```