# combobox items add (an item of a class) how to do this (see code inside)

Tags: vb.net

So I have and assignment for visual basic and I have some lines with this setup:

```
Me.ArticlesComboBox.Items.Add(New Article(code:="xxx", name:="xxxxx", unitPrice:=xxx)
```

I don't understand what the code:= means?
I have a class Article with the properties code and name as string and unitPrice as decimal.

The error I have is: **'code' is not a parameter of 'Public Sub New()'.**

All help is welcome :)

Comment: I think you are looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936224/c-sharp-to-vb-net-syntax-conversion-for-class-instantiation-with-properties

Comment: I'm not sure if that is what I need, I just think it's weird why the code:= or name:= is there. Does that have a special meaning/syntax?

Comment: yes it does. code:=value means you are setting the arguments of the method. for example, Public Sub MySub(code As String, name as String), you can do the following - MySub(name:="xxx", code:="yyy"). notice they are now not provided in the same order they were requested in.

Comment: if the Article class is yours, post its ctor (Sub New). otherwise Intellisense should be telling you how the params needed to create an instance of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that Article needs a constructor that looks like this

```
Public Sub New(code As String, name As String, unitPrice As Decimal)

End Sub
```

In the constructor assign the variables to the properties of the class.

Comment: So like this:
Public Class Article
    Public Property code As String
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property unitPrice As Decimal
    Public Sub New(C As String, N As String, uP As Decimal)
        code = C
        name = N
        unitPrice = uP
    End Sub
End Class